# how to extract lines between two patterns only with awk?

Tags: shell, awk

```
$ awk '/abc/{flag=1; next} /edf/{flag=0} flag' file
```

flag will print `$0`, but I only need the first matching lines from two strings.

input:

```
abc
111
222
edf
333
444
abc
555
666
edf
```

output:

```
111
222
```

Comment: can you post a sample input and desired output?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages.  You have not expressed your problem clearly yet.  Do you want to see the PAT1 line?  Do you want to see the PAT2 line?  Do you want to see all the lines in between the PAT1 and PAT2 lines, or only some of them (and if you only want to see some of them, which do you want to see).  A simple sample input with the expected output would be helpful — almost necessary.

Answer (score 1):

So I'm assuming you want to print out the matching lines only for 1st occurrence.

For that you can just use an additional variable and set it once `flag` goes `0`

```
$ cat file 
abc
111
222
edf
333
444
abc
555
666
edf
$ awk '/abc/{flag=1; next} /edf/{if(flag) got1stoccurence=1; flag=0} flag && !got1stoccurence' file
111
222
```

Comment: Note that if an `edf` line appears before the first `abc` line, your code won't output anything.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes missed that .. fixed it

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the first set of output, then:

```
awk '/abc/{flag=1; next} /edf/{if (flag == 1) exit} flag' file
```

Or:

```
awk '/abc/{flag++; next} /edf/{if (flag == 1) flag++} flag == 1' file
```

There are other ways to do it too, no doubt.  The first is simple and to the point.  The second is more flexible if you also want to process the first group of lines appearing between another pair of patterns.

Note that if the input file contains:

```
xyz
edf
pqr
abc
111
222
edf
```

It is important not to do anything about the first `edf`; it is an uninteresting line because no `abc` line has been read yet.

Answer (score 0):

Using `getline` with `while`:

```
$ awk '/abc/ { while(getline==1 && $0!="edf") print; exit }' file
111
222
```

Look for `/abc/` and once found records will be outputed in the `while` loop until `edf` is found.

Comment: Could you show how to tweak that to print "got it" every time a line contains any letter? The point is the result will be a complete rewrite and/or a mess of duplicate conditions for just the slightest requirements change courtesy of the use of getline. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for more info on how/when to use getline.

Comment: Not sure I got your point there but: `cat file | sed 's/222/2s2/g' | awk '/abc/ { while(getline==1 && $0!="edf") print ($0~/[a-z]/?"got it":$0); exit }'`

Comment: That script doesn't do what I was asking for, it'd be something more like `/[a-z]/{print "got it"} /abc/ { while(getline==1) if ($0!="edf") print; else if ($0~/[a-z]/) print "got it"; exit }' file` i.e. you have to duplicate the condition `/[a-z]/` and associated action because each line can be read by awks normal processing loop or by the getline loop and the result has duplicate code and is hard to understand, especially given such a tiny additional requirement.

Comment: It would also introduce interesting complexity if you have multiple files since the getline loop can jump across file boundaries so the output could start in 1 file and end in the next even if neither file contained both the start and end expressions. That's easy to protect against using normal processing but much harder with an embedded getline loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '/edf/{exit} f; /abc/{f=1}' file
111
222
```

If it was possible for edf to appear before abc in your input then it'd be:

```
$ awk 'f{if (/edf/) exit; print} /abc/{f=1}' file
111
222
```